# Combining 3 columns in a data frame which are string lists

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have multiple columns in dataframe. Say 3 columns are A.B and C . I would like combine them to get comb as a the output.

I tried string joining after converting each column to string using astype  but I am getting a nested list which I am unable to convert to a single list.

```
 A            B              C                   comb
         

['300','200']   ['a','x']     ['P50.9','R17']      ['300','200','a','x',P50.9','R17']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use if there are lists:

```
df['comb'] = df.A + df.B + df.C
```

If there are strings:

```
import ast

f = lambda x: [z for y in x.apply(ast.literal_eval) for z in y]
df['comb'] = df[['A','B','C']].agg(f, axis=1)
```

Or:

```
df['comb'] = (df.A.apply(ast.literal_eval) + 
              df.B.apply(ast.literal_eval) + 
              df.C.apply(ast.literal_eval))
```

Comment: What should I do if they are strings. If I do this I get the output as  '[' 300','200'] ['a','x'] '